# Configuring Lotus Notes email notification in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lotus-notes

It's my first time creating an email notification function for ASP.Net in MVC and still learning the basic stuff as of now. I have several questions from the codes, which I'm still studying, here: [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1822965.aspx?Send%20an%20Email%20using%20Lotus%20Notes%20Server%20programmatically).

1.`sServerName` - From where can I find the server name in Lotus Notes? I have no idea what value to put here.

2.`password` - Will I be using the sender's Lotus Notes password here?

3.I'm planning to put the codes below as an `ActionResult` in the `Controller` which will be called by a button in the `View`. This method will return the `View` after the email finishes execution. Is this correct?

4.I have noticed that the port was not defined, is it okay if the port will not be defined? Based on my reasearch, LN uses port 25 when using SMTP to receive and send email.

```
NotesSession _notesSession = new NotesSession();
NotesDocument _notesDocument = null;
string sServerName = "ServerName";
string sMailFile = "mail\\UserName.nsf";
string password = "Password";
string sSendTo = "emailaddress.domain.com";
string sSubject = "Testmail";
_notesSession.Initialize(password);
NotesDatabase _notesDataBase = _notesSession.GetDatabase(sServerName, sMailFile, false);

if (!_notesDataBase.IsOpen)
{
_notesDataBase.Open();
}

_notesDocument = _notesDataBase.CreateDocument();
_notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
_notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", sSendTo);
_notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", sSubject);
NotesRichTextItem _richTextItem = _notesDocument.CreateRichTextItem("Body");
_richTextItem.AppendText("Test only message. " + "\r\n");
_notesDocument.Send(false);
_richTextItem =null;
_notesDocument =null;
_notesDataBase =null;
_notesSession =null;
```

Comment: Philip, you don't want to travel down that path. It is dark and painful. The COM support for Notes isn't meant for server class communication

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do this. Reaching out from ASP.NET requires the Net/COM bridge and then DCOM if the server isn't on the same machine. Notes, talking its own protocol uses port 1352, not 25. You have better options:

- Use a generic SMTP library for dotNET and talk to the Domino server using SMTP
- Use the [Command line eMail client](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/command%20line%20email%20client) and just span an OS task to talk to it
- sweet talk your Domino developer in providing you a web service to talk to (easy to build in Domino), so you can comfortably speak HTTP
- Be a little more adventurous and use the (undocumented) HTTP API as described in a [series of blog entries](http://notessensei.com/blog/2014/11/poking-around-the-inotes-http-api-part-1.html).

Using COM/DCOM is the very last thing you want to do.

Comment: The code he's using assumes the Notes client is installed on the machine where the code is running.  It does use COM, but DCOM and what port to connect to are irrelevant, those are handled by the client itself.  That aside, using an SMTP library is still far easier for sending a simple email.

Comment: With DCOM you could get away without an installed Notes client on the same machine - if you manage to setup dcom correctly. But nobody does that anymore. I concur with Duston: SMTP is the way to go. Keeps you independent from the mail backend in use

Comment: @Duston so this code is for client, but that wasn't what I need. Our Notes runs on server. I've contacted our team which handles the database, and given me a stored procedure that already handles the sending of email. I just need to set the parameters. It turns out that we cannot run from client side but only in server side only. That's why we can use the SP only. Anyway, thanks for all of your comments. It helped me a lot to understand SMTP for Louts Notes